# Count all chords in undirected graph

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, discrete-mathematics

I've such task: count all chords in undirected graph. I have an idea to firsly find all cycles in the graph and then check the nodes of the cycles if are they connected. Is there any more efficient algorithm? Thanks for your help!
 p.s: graph is represented as Adjacency matrix.

Comment: *count all chords in undirected graph.* -- I have never seen the term "chord" used in the context of an undirected graph.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie See [Chordal graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_graph)

Comment: Well, I learned something new today.

Comment: My approach would be to find the biggest cycles in the graph first. By biggest cycle I mean if a node is part of more than one cycle (because it's one of the endpoints of a cord), then choose for it to be part of the biggest cycle. Once you have found all the cycles, you can find chords inside a cycle by a simple DFS. I am not sure about the correctness of the whole algorithm though.

Comment: Are you asked to count the number of edges that are chords, or are you asked to count the number of cycles that have chords? Those are different problems and the solution would look different.

Comment: I'm asked to count the number of edges that are chords of course